# Не устанавливается загрузочный экран SplashScreen для мобильного приложения на cordova

Tags: cordova

Пишу мобильное приложение с помощью cordova.
Проблема заключается в том что не отображается загрузочный экран SplashScreen, при открытии мобильного приложения, вместо него открывается стандартный загрузочный экран androidStudio.

Версия cordova - 12.0.0

Использую плагин splashscreen. Добавил изображения в папку res/screen/android/ со всеми разрешениями указанными в доке, но загруженное изображение не отображается.

config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="app.site.ru" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>site</name>
    <description>App</description>
    <author email="korobko.11@inbox.ru" href="https://cordova.apache.org">
        Korobko
    </author>

    <icon src="res/ico.png"/>

<platform name="android">
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xxhdpi.png"/>

    <!-- Landscape -->
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-hdpi.png"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-ldpi.png"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-mdpi.png"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-xhdpi.png"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-xxhdpi.png"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-xxxhdpi.png"/>

    <!-- Portrait -->
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xxhdpi.png"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xxxhdpi.png"/>
  
    <!-- Dark Mode -->
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-night-hdpi.png"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-night-ldpi.png"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-night-mdpi.png"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-night-xhdpi.png" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-night-xxhdpi.png"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-night-xxxhdpi.png"/>

    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-night-hdpi.png"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-night-ldpi.png"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-night-mdpi.png"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-night-xhdpi.png" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-night-xxhdpi.png"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-night-xxxhdpi.png" />
</platform>

    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
    <preference name = "SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value = "true" />

    <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait"/>
    <preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="1000000"/>
    <preference name="CRIPageLoadPromtInterval" value="200"/>
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false"/>
    <preference name="StatusBarDefaultScrollToTop" value="false"/> 

    <content src="https://site/index.php" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://site/*"/>

    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />

    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWebViewEngine" />
    <preference name="CordovaDefaultWebViewEngine" value="CDVWebViewEngine" />
</widget>
```

Если splash находится внутри тэга platform, то при сборке проекта консоль выдает warning о том, что splash устарел и необходимо использовать тэг preference с значением AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon. Но данный подход устанавливает только иконку внутри загрузочного экрана, поэтому такой вариант не подходит.

Так же пробовал закидывать файлы в app/src/main/res/drawable, в эмуляторе сначала отображается стандартный загрузочный экран потом на несколько секунд появляется уже мое изображение, на реальном устройстве отображается только стандартный загрузочный экран.

Так же пробовал использовать следующий подход.

```
 <preference name = "SplashScreen" value = "splash" />
 <splash src="res/screen/splash.png"/>
```